# How to dynamically add click button to an html table in D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Right now I have the following D3 code that updates a table.  The first column is filled by the strings in data, the second column should be a button that when clicked prints a string to the console.  The relevant non-working code is below:

```
function update_table(old_table, data, which_div) {
    var columns = ["value", "button"];
    table.select("tbody").remove();
    var tbody = table.append("tbody");
    var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr").data(data).enter().append("tr");
    var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
        .data(function (d) {
           return columns.map(function (column) {
              return { column: column, text: d};
        });
    }).enter()
    .append("td")
    .html(function (d) {  
        if (d.column === columns[0]) return d.text;
        else if (d.column === columns[1]) {
            return "<button onclick="+clickaction(d)+">"+"Click me!</button>";
        }
    });
return table ;
}

function clickaction(d) {
    console.log("hi");
}
```

The buttons in each table show on the screen but the problem is that *every time* the table is updated, `console.log("hi")` gets called.  Not when the button is clicked on.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Tried your first suggestion, still no go.  How do I append a button to the elements in the second column from within the else if statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more elegant way to do this would be to append the text `<td>`s and then append the button `<td>`s. Then you could append the buttons directly in the second column.

```
// Append the first column, using the data already stored in the rows
rows.append("td").html(function(d){ return d; });

// Append the second column, which has no text but contains a button
// with an onclick function
var buttonColumn = rows.append("td");
buttonColumn.append("button")
    .text("Click me!")
    .on("click", function(d){ return clickaction(d); });
```

---

If however you want to use your current approach,  you could append a `<button>` using D3 within the `<td>`, which will allow you to use `button.on("click", function(){ ... })`:

```
.html(function (d) {  
    if (d.column === columns[0]) return d.text;
    else if (d.column === columns[1]) {
        // Append a button as a side-effect
        var button = d3.select(this).append("button")
            .text("Click me!")
            .on("click", function(){ clickaction(d); })
        // Return nothing
        return "";
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried both your more elegent way (really nice!) and the way I was doing it.  The button shows up, table looks great, still nothing happens on click!

Comment: @Andre5: hmm strange. Could you try adding a `console.log("Hello")` before calling `clickaction` in the `.on("click", ...)`? Does that do anything?

Comment: I put this: .on("click", function(d){ console.log("hi"); });  Nothing prints to console.  Its like everything works except it never makes it to the ".on(...)" part of the code

Comment: @Andre5: I don't know what's going on. Could you post the rest of your code, or create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Wow OK, while making the fiddle I found my problem.  I had "pointer-events: none;" in my CSS for the table rows left over from a copy/paste job.  Your answer works great, thank you!